# pd.merge error : name 'filename' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling

```
pd.merge(train_1, train_2 , on = 'PassengerId', how = 'outer')
```

After giving the above command, I get the following error :-

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_3076\3752885088.py in <module>
----> 1 pd.merge(train_1, train_2 , on = 'PassengerId', how = 'outer')

NameError: name 'train_1' is not defined
```

I was trying to merge 2 files - train1 and train2. I wanted an outer join. But it is not able to find the file it seems. But I am able to read the train_1 and train_2 files using pd.read_excel command.

Comment: as error message says, `train_1` is not defined. check that variable with `print(train_1)`

Comment: Getting the same error.

Comment: I am able to execute this cmd                                                                                                  pd.read_excel("train_1.xlsx")

Comment: can you please edit your original post to show us where/how `train_1` variable is defined? Ideally, if you can show us the entirety of your codebase that is relevant, we can have a better idea of what is causing this. Thanks!

Comment: Do `train_1  = pd.read_excel("train_1.xlsx")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you read a `train_1.xlsx` file, Python does not create a `train_1` variable. You must define the variable using the `=` sign.

As your code suggests, you forgot to declare `train_1` variable (maybe `train_2` too):

```
----> 1 pd.merge(train_1, train_2 , on = 'PassengerId', how = 'outer')
```

> But I am able to read the train_1 and train_2 files using pd.read_excel command.

You have to replace:

```
pd.read_excel('train_1.xlsx', ...)
pd.read_excel('train_2.xlsx', ...)
```

With:

```
train_1 = pd.read_excel('train_1.xlsx', ...)
train_2 = pd.read_excel('train_2.xlsx', ...)
```

About [`NameError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NameError) exception